# Implement horizontal scroll view like Slide Image Gallery?

Tags: android, uiimageview, horizontalscrollview

i want to implement Image Gallery that load from url and put it into horizontal scroll view . i want to set my image view into match_parent  but it doesn't work .. how to get a view like this ??[image]

And this is my xml and view .

```
<HorizontalScrollView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="300dp"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_margin="12dp"
            android:id="@+id/slideshow">

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="horizontal">

                <com.android.volley.toolbox.NetworkImageView
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:id="@+id/slide1"
                    android:scaleType="fitXY"
                    android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher"/>

                <com.android.volley.toolbox.NetworkImageView
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:id="@+id/slide2"
                    android:scaleType="centerInside"
                    android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher"/>

                <com.android.volley.toolbox.NetworkImageView
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:id="@+id/slide3"
                    android:scaleType="centerCrop"
                    android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher"/>
            </LinearLayout>
        </HorizontalScrollView>
```

[image]

Comment: you need to set the width for your images programatically , but i actually don't recommend using this way to view images gallery cuz it will consume lots of your device RAM and you are absolutely getting outOfMemoryException.
so to avoid that you need to use some adapter view ... a RecyclerView will do great

Answer (score 0):

Use [RelativeLayout](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/RelativeLayout.html) instead of LinearLayout and align the elements using [rightOf](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.html#attr_android:layout_toRightOf)

Comment: imageview still won't fit a view .. i've set it to match_parent each of image view .

Comment: i guess this happens because of your parent View is wrap_content and the childs are match_parent ... maybe you try to [get Screen size](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/Display.html#getSize%28android.graphics.Point%29) and set it programatically to your imageViews

Comment: i used android:isScrollContainer="true"
                    android:adjustViewBounds="true"

Comment: and it want to fit height parent .. now if i want to set it match_parent it will strech .. and if i define with dp , it looks good .. http://postimg.org/image/8ac993ew9/

Answer (score 0):

After some investigation I made to solve similar problem for myself, I came up to using [ViewPager](https://developer.android.com/training/animation/screen-slide). I think, that is what you wanted to do.